# Capacitor in AC

Tags: capacitor, ac, amperage

I am new in this sphere and I would be appreciated to have some help. So I have this schema, and I don't understand what is the reason that the value of the capacitor amperage decreases after every phase?
I was supposed that the amplitude would be the same in each phase, but it decreases.

I spent 3 days for this so please help me to understand. Thank you

[image]

Comment: Does it make a difference if you remove that Ground symbol from the transformer's primary circuit?

Comment: We can't answer this question if the pwl source isn't described

Comment: Why do students insist on showing LEDs and bridge output voltages upside down?  This diagram uses a negative DC supply that should be shown below ground = 0V by definition.  This is a "LOGIC DIAGRAM" nothing else.

Answer (score 3):

> *I don't understand what is the reason that the value of the capacitor
> amperage decreases after every phase? I was supposed that the
> amplitude would be the same in each phase, but it decreases.*

After the AC sine wave power source is first applied, it takes time for things to stabilize. If you left the simulator running for much longer, you'd see what I mean. Basically, if you look at the DC voltage across the capacitor, you'd see it slowly charging in short bursts that occur on each of the power sine wave's positive and negative peak. Eventually, a capacitor voltage is reached where the losses due to the load exactly equal the energy fed from the AC power source.

This could take anything up to a second to happen. Only at this point will the capacitor current waveform be the same on subsequent cycles.

Comment: Thanks for reply. So there is no connection between phases of AC wave power source and phases of capacitor. The capacitor will have full charge and only after that will start discharging, right?

Comment: Your assessment does not make any sense. There is a **fundamental connection** between AC phases and capacitor charging. Look at the capacitor voltage waveform as I implied.

Answer (score 1):

I can see some reasons why this diagram took you 3 days and me a few minutes to understand your logic diagram.

> Why do students insist on showing LEDs and bridge output voltages upside down? This diagram uses a negative DC supply that should be shown below ground = 0V by definition. This is a "LOGIC DIAGRAM" nothing else.

- To communicate and understand electronic logic ;
  Gnd = 0V  by definition
- It is logically above negative voltages and below positive voltages.
- Symbols should be taught & drawn this way.  This is not like words written right to left or left to right. All flow is universally left to right in Logic.
- You have a Positively grounded rectifier,
- the cap polarity is backward.
- the LED is Anode grounded, given R flow direction, current is positive
- given your 1mF cap load, huge currents in Amps are needed from AC source to charge up the voltage , JUST to power xx mA to the LED .

### **What's wrong with this design? besides above**

- no expectations or specifications or "SPECS"

  - C too big
  - use 200 Hz peak pulse to LED to I average rather than DC with no flicker , unless you need high power DC

[image]

---

The 4 diode switches or a diode full-bridge rectify the positive current with twice the  input frequency and almost the same voltage minus the 2 alternating diode pair forward voltage of 0.7V x2 approx.

When the output R*C value product = 10 ms is equal the input period or two half periods of 5ms the Vpp ripple is about 1/3rd of the peak DC voltage. This means a bigger Cap is needed to follow the input peaks so that the exponential decay is higher before the next peak.

The 1A diodes here conduct with about 1 ohm while the load is shown as 100 Ohms so the rise/fall times depend on the current limiting of that resistance for slew rates. dV/dt = Ic/C  When a diagonal pair of diodes conduct, they feed both the capacitors and the loads. So the diode current duty factor is almost the same as the voltage ripple/DC ratio.  When the ripple reduces greatly the diodes muct pump that much more current in lesser time to match the energy of the load.

[Here is an interactive simulation](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjAzCAMB00IQDhrAnAFiQdmxArEhAGwFL4BMxIWI%20NK%20ApgLRhgBQAbiGtRRmi9q7CjHDgE4MUNmx8HAO7DwYMRQGqZHACYgNGLfqQow2alB1MAZgEMArgBsALrv2aBQiifDmQlmwcXNzBiITN%20TVF-ECs7J1c9UPC-A31BGLig12U0zxV86CVwMN8RUopsbVyfCP8SMphi5P0q%20v42ooBjdsaIBsqZVEQwXlhzbGgIPGx8WbAMNGHoTmV%20kT8MUMaKYvXWsS2O7QAnGm26o4PxMAQOAA8afFGKCEOkF4IaEpBHAHtbDoOABzXqDME%20WQcQRQCDQQxsagYN4McTQAD6SHRGLU%20AwxHR7HQaBJxAot2gpJW2Gx8AQYHRbHREEJLJxLIg0Km-nhICQQmRYgWhnCGKxOORxDMtJGtIw2FCFDQlOg%20GIW2g2AwjIZFEJGM5AAdzhskbQ6qMRRw-uAoChws8Pi85EMhbCOEA) where you change any value, slow it down or run faster and much more.  Dots show the flow of charges by the electronic convention for current.

[image]

ANSWER:

Since the Diode resistance is small the current peaks are in phase with the voltage.  But if it were a sine wave with large resistance then the voltage drop on the series resistor would reflect the capacitor and load current and tend to lag the input voltage up to 90 degrees with no load.

Comment: Who did not understand my correct answer and why?

Comment: I got it, many thanks.